# Gridview Conditional formatting of a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview  and I want the cell that exists on 3rd row and  6th column coordinates to take as a background the file image.jpg. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help    ....

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
 if(e.Row.Index=1) //Check your Row index 
  {
      e.Row.Cells[YOur column index].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/nc.png) no-repeat 5px center;");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this set the image for the entire row. I want to change the background of a specific cell. The cell that exists in the 3rd row and in the 6th column